# Changing multiple Internet Option in IE8 for all users

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to change some Internet Options for all users that log into a laptop (on a domain).  Things like, turning off the popup blocker, "Check for newer versions of stored pages" changed to "Every time I visit the webpage" and adding a Trusted site.  I don't want to do this through GPO (although I know this would be easier).  I want to be able to run a script or have 1 "Super User" that would control these settings.

Can anyone out there help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: +1 for utility the word "Super User" to a post on SuperUser.com. If you have GPO (Group Policy Objects) to set the security for you, why wouldn't you want to use it and reinvent the wheel? What do you benefit by not using GPO?

Comment: I would love to know why you don't want to use GPO, especially given that you already know it would be easier. Hehe, "super user", indeed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of that can be managed by running gpedit.msc  This should open up a window where the left pane has two main sections with multiple sub sections.  Near the bottom of each main section there's a windows subsection.  In those, there's internet explorer subsections.  Things you change in the top area are per computer.  Things in the bottom, affect the current user.  What you can't do in these areas, you can likely set (custom option) in the security tab of inetcpl.cpl.   One thing to note is that the pop-up management reference in gpedit.msc isn't about turning off popups, its about turning of the management of popups.  Websites that query your page to see if popups are enabled don't get a response if the management is turned off.  This means that even if popups are enabled, the sites querying IE will assume that its disabled anyway.  Also, both of these only affect IE, so you'll need to configure each browser separately to achieve similar results.  For firefox, the settings are usually in files in the mozilla paths of the users profile that end in tags like .js, .properties, and .config.  hope this helps